# Are Tries appropriate for languages which have no alphabet?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to work out the most efficient way for achieving similar efficiency as if using a Trie to store english words, but instead I want to store words in languages that have no alphabet such as Chinese. For example I want to be able to load a word list and have an application which as the user is typing gives suggestions in real time based on the characters typed already. Any suggestions how this could be achieved as if I use Tries I will have enormous number of parent nodes as there are thousands unique characters. Is there any established way for achieving what I have described above ?

Comment: You mean `Trees`, not `Tries`?

Comment: No, I think tries is the correct term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Tries are special kinds of trees

Comment: Yes, Trie is what I mean, and it is a common DS for dictionary applications but for languages with alphabet - in my case I need similar efficiency with languages that don't have alphabet

Comment: How are words in such languages typed? If they are typed as multiple keyboard presses, a trie can be built based on these key presses. If not... well, can you make suggestions in that case?

Comment: This is not really an issue, I think I can use the unicode of the characters to build Ternary Search Trie, but again from my understanding this will be massive (in terms of memory) as I will end up having thousands of parent nodes and not many child nodes (unless I am missing something obvious and this can be done some other way...) A bit of background: a character is actually a word as well however 2 characters can form completely different word

Comment: Thinking of Chinese specifically, can we look at it based on the pinyin?  For example: 汉语 would be "Hànyŭ".

Comment: I thought about this, but I think I will have the same problem. For example in english we know that we have 26 possible starting points and from there a  Ternary Search Trie can be build which will work efficiently, in Chinese each symbol is a word but also can be part of longer word which means something else and this means there are thousands unique starting points and possibly good chance of running out of memory. Again I have not tested this, so I was hoping someone may have faced this problem before. Whether I use pinyin or unicode of the symbol it will be the same

Comment: @JoeC Chinese has way too many words with the same pinyin for a tree based on that to be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A terminological detour: the word "alphabet" is commonly used to refer to the symbols in writing systems (like those of the various European languages) where each symbol roughly corresponds to a single phoneme (sound). There are also writing systems in which symbols correspond to syllables, morphemes or whole words; the symbols of such languages, which are much more numerous than alphabets, have different technical names: syllabaries, abugida, logographs, and so on, but the discrimination is not precise.

In computational theory, however, it is usual to use the word "alphabet" to describe any finite collection of symbols, regardless of how small or large the set is. Any alphabet -- or finite set of symbols -- can be transcoded into fixed-length sequences from a smaller alphabet of size at least two, with a change in length which is logarithmic in the size of the alphabet. Consequently, it is often convenient to assume that only binary representations are used: that is, representations from the alphabet `{0, 1}`.

A trie will work with any alphabet size; there is no requirement that the trie's alphabet be an "alphabet" from a human writing system, nor is there a prohibition against it being a larger collection of symbols, although naïve implementations with large alphabets can be very wasteful of space. In particular, nothing stops you from using a recoding of the original written characters into a smaller alphabet, using several trie levels for each character. For example, if the original string is represented in UTF-8, then you could use individual bytes (and you might want to distinguish between leading nodes, where the alphabet size is 178 although only 99 correspond to "letters", and interior nodes, where the alphabet size is 64). Alternatively, you could just split the Unicode code-point into three or four bit-sequences, each of a manageable size.

You can optimize tries by compressing successive nodes which have only a single child; that may be effective with the above schemes. A compact trie over the binary alphabet is called a Patricia trie, and it might be worth looking at as well.

Another common solution for dealing with sparse trie nodes is to use some kind of associative structure for children, rather than an array. In [ternary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree), the children are simply kept in a sorted list so that the correct child can be found with a binary search in time logarithmic in the alphabet size, which is constant for a given alphabet. (The time is actually logarithmic in the number of children, which could be much smaller than the alphabet size.)

Another solution, practical for medium-sized alphabets, is to keep a bit vector of present children as well as a sorted vector of children; modern CPUs have instructions which can rapidly sum the number of set bits in a word, making it efficient to use the bit vector to find the index of the child in the vector.

Yet another possible solution is to use a hash table whose entries are keyed by a 2-tuple consisting of the parent node's id and the child's leading character. This data structure is easy to maintain and space-efficient, but has very poor locality of reference. (One disadvantage is that additional work needs to be done to construct the list of children of a parent node: for example, by explicitly linking the children.)